# Differential cross section in nuclear reaction

Tags: nuclear-physics

[image]

While explaining Compound Nucleus Mechanism of Nuclear Reactions, our professor gave us the graph that I have posted in the picture above. However, no further information was given or explained.

I just cannot understand what this graph has to do with the compound nucleus mechanism, nor am I finding any explanation in my Nuclear Physics Books (Nuclear Physics by S N Ghoshal, and Introductory Nuclear Physics by Krane). Where may I find some suitable explanation? Any thread to some link will be highly appreciated.

Comment: That is a pretty broad topic. Are you hung up on the differential cross section, the compound nucleus, the specific reaction, or what?

Comment: The reaction seems to be like ${25}_{Mg}+ f \rightarrow f+ {25}_{Mg}$. First I can't read what is written in the brackets, I named it $f$, may it is a $\gamma$ or a neutron. Anyway, it is a differential cross section, and the angle is probably the angle under which the second $f$ is emitted. So probably it is the differential cross section of the formation of the compound nucleus of Mg (Actually it could also be the decay of the compound). If I knew better I would write an answer, so due to all these unknowns it is only a comment. But may be it helps.

Comment: @Jon Custer   I'm trying to figure out how this graph is related to the Compound Nucleus Mechanism. Also, I don't have a clear idea about reaction cross sections.

Comment: @Frederic Thomas     The quantities inside the brackets are (p, p). So they are protons.

Comment: If $f$ is a proton or something else finally does not matter  much. I guess hitting ${25}^{Mg}$  with a proton creates a compound nucleus for a short time $1e-9$s, which decays back to the original components. The only thing which is unusual is that the proton is emitted again since this could be suppressed by the Coulomb barrier. The differential cross section with angle is rather flat, i.e. the proton emission (in the end state) can happen under almost any angle with a similar probability. I don't know why the diff. cross section is so flat & if it typical for a compound nucleus. Consult WP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The figure shows the contribution of the compound nucleus formation for the elastic scattering of protons on Mg-25.  The x-axis is the scattering angle and y-axis is the differential cross section. A simple elastic scattering cross section would probably show more structure that indicated in the drawing.  Hence the compound nucleus reaction washes out any structure resulting in the relatively flat differential cross-section with an unexpected increase at large scattering angle.

I don't know for sure what point the professor was pushing but the description above is what the paper is trying to convey I believe.

Comment: The simple elastic scattering cross section would, of course, be the Rutherford cross section, which is quite different as a function of scattering angle.